# SELECT em relacionamento N:N sem usar INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu preciso de um SQL equivalente a um SELECT usando INNER JOIN, pois estou usando o SphinxSearch e li que ele não suporta INNER JOIN. Sei que tem como fazer usando Sub-Query mas não lembro como faz.

Este é o banco: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19xMK57H1QfLcLHJer4FV4LMf3QD2DHE_)

Este é o SELECT:

```
SELECT projeto.id, orientador.idOrientador 
    FROM projeto INNER JOIN projeto_has_orientador ON (projeto.id = projeto_has_orientador.Projeto_id ) 
        INNER JOIN orientador ON (projeto_has_orientador.Orientador_idOrientador = orientador.idOrientador);
```

Essa foi uma tentativa sem sucesso de criar um SELECT com Sub-Query:

```
SELECT projeto.id, orientador.idOrientador 
FROM projeto, orientador 
    WHERE projeto.id 
    IN (SELECT Projeto_id FROM projeto_has_orientador WHERE Orientador_idOrientador
    IN (SELECT idOrientador FROM orientador);
```

Grato.

Comment: tem q saber qual resultado vc está esperando com isso... se eu entendi... => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1996d71/1

Comment: Entendendo que por **ele não suporta INNER JOIN** você queira dizer apenas a interpretação do operador **INNER JOIN** tente:
`SELECT projeto.id, orientador.idOrientador 
    FROM projeto, projeto_has_orientador, orientador
  WHERE projeto.id = projeto_has_orientador.Projeto_id
      AND projeto_has_orientador.Orientador_idOrientador = orientador.idOrientador;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabou que nem precisei da sub-query, pois acontece o seguinte no Sphinx:

Eu tenho um arquivo de configuração no qual eu coloco o SELECT em que ele irá fazer no banco para indexar os registros, nesse arquivo eu consigo usar o INNER JOIN, pois ele segue a linguagem SQL do banco em que ele irá fazer o índice.

Depois do índice feito, ele tem uma linguagem própria para fazer a pesquisa em cima dos registros indexados, esta que não suporta INNER JOIN.

Eu somente pedi para ele criar um índice em cima de um SELECT com INNER JOIN, que daí ele indexaria os resultados em uma só tabela no Sphinx.

Answer (score 1):

Pra fazer o JOIN precisaria de haver um relacionamento com chave estrangeira entre as tabelas. Por exemplo, seria inserir em qual projeto o orientador esta:

```
ALTER TABLE orientador ADD COLUMN projeto_id INTEGER;

ALTER TALBE orientador ADD CONSTRAINT fk_projeto_orientador 
FOREIGN KEY (projeto_id) REFERENCES projeto(id);
```

Ai o SQL de JOIN poderia ser usado:

```
SELECT projeto.id, orientador.idOrientador
FROM projeto
INNER JOIN orientador ON orientador.projeto_id = projeto.id;
```

Isso foi apenas um exemplo. Se seu orientador pode estar contido em mais de um projeto talvez seja interessante criar uma chave estrangeira de projeto para orientador e não o contrario com fiz acima.

Veja:

Chave estrangeira: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Entidade e relacionamento: https://www.devmedia.com.br/modelo-entidade-relacionamento-mer-e-diagrama-entidade-relacionamento-der/14332

Comment: Pelo padrão SQL não é obrigatório a especificação de uma chave estrangeira para utilizar uma junção, qualquer tipo de JOIN. O que se exige é que os campos utilizados na junção sejam comparáveis.

Comment: Compreendo bem a não obrigatoriedade. Sugeri a chave estrangeira porque senti a necessidade de ter uma. Fica melhor compreendido as relações com o uso. Ainda mais quando trata-se da abstração de projeto e orientado do projeto. Melhor padronização, e redução de código desnecessário.

Comment: De toda forma, quis ajudar, e acho que qualquer solução que traga o efeito desejado é o suficiente

Comment: No SQL que enviei continha as "Foreign Keys", pois se trata de um relacionamento de N para N, no caso, existe uma tabela no meio, que é a Projeto_has_Orientador, que faz a junção dos projetos com os orientadores. A informação que eu estava querendo, é como eu faço para ter um SELECT que faz o mesmo papel de um INNER JOIN, pois o SphinxSearch realmente não suporta.

Comment: legal cara, confesso que não prestei a atenção. Eu o post tentei ajudar em meio as pressas :D